# How can I access embedded iframe table data in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have a embedded my Excel table in a HTML file. The question is how can I access the data of this embedded table? I need to create a search box which return rows that includes the value you entered:

[image]

This is the embedded excel code:

```
<iframe width="90%" height="900" frameborder="0" align = "center" scrolling="no" src="https://sharepoint.com/sites/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={b93faff9-7c24-40f3-bf62-aafe239aff18}&action=embedview&Item=Table1&wdHideGridlines=True&wdDownloadButton=True&wdInConfigurator=True"></iframe>//embed EXcel file from SharePoint
```

Comment: In short - you can't. There is no easy way to jump into the iframe's sandbox and read the data from the page that hosts the iframe. This is for security reasons, There are ways of the two speaking to each other but this requires the JavaScript at both sides.

Comment: OK. Thanks! Got it.